# How do I view the keyboard buffer?

Tags: keyboard, history

I would like to be able to find some passwords I forgot to wright down.
I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

update 
I realize I cant find passwords on the buffer but i would like to know how to read the keyboard buffer  through the terminal.

Comment: Hm..., passwords are not stored in keyboard buffers.

Comment: How do you figure to manage this? If would be a blatant security flaw if you could find passwords like this. Passwords are tested against what you type in as a password and will never show up in a buffer (unless the actual password is used in a command in plain text like mysql's `--password` ;)). Btw. all passwords can be reset if you have a sudo user account and the sudo password can be reset from grub and/or a live cd if need be. You might be better off asking how to reset a particular password.

Comment: Are you referring to passwords remembered by your web browser, by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I'll just put what @mikewhatever said in an answer:

Keys that you pressed in the past are not stored anywhere.